# Count the changes in the list grouped by ID

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe df which looks like this:
And output columns is to be calculated

```
ID       input     OUTPUT
1         A,B      1
1         B,C,D    2   
1         C        1
2         E,f      1
2         A,B,C    3
3         E        0
```

Can anyone please help me how to calculate the changes in the output column based on the input value and whenever the ID changes the output will be zero even if the previous element of the list is different

In row 1 output is 1 because there is only one change from A to B
in 2 row there are two changes from B to C and C to D.
in row 2 it will be one because previous element of the last list was D.
When ID changes we will not compare with the previous row, so E to F only 1 change

Comment: I guess it's per ID @yatu

Comment: Seems like it should be 2 to me, just as in the second output

Comment: becuase F to A one change then A to B and B to C- @yatu

Comment: In second case, last element of first row was B and first element of second row was also B so no change, there will be two change only from B to C and C to D

Comment: Then in the third row shouldn't it be 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
# get the last element from the previous row
prev_row = df.groupby('ID').input.shift().str.split(',').str[-1]

# concatenate with the next element, construct a set and
# count the amount of elements
df['OUTPUT'] = (prev_row.str.cat(df.input, sep=',')
                .fillna(df.input)
                .str.split(',')
                .map(set)
                .str.len()
                .sub(1))

print(df)

   ID  input  OUTPUT
0   1    A,B       1
1   1  B,C,D       2
2   1      C       1
3   2    E,f       1
4   2  A,B,C       3
5   3      E       0
```

Comment: Applying 'set' will fail in this case:  df.loc[6]=[4,"A,A,B,A,C,D,A,E"]

Answer (score 1):

I append a new row to the test data for testing, see the output:

```
df["idchng"]= df.ID.diff().ge(1)
df["lastch"]= df.input.str.rpartition(",")[2].shift()
print(df,"\n")

df["inp2"]= np.where(df.idchng, df.input, df.lastch.str.cat(df.input,sep=","))
df.inp2.iat[0]= df.input.iat[0]

def diffstr(s):
    ser= pd.Series(s.split(","))
    return ser.ne(ser.shift()).sum()-1

df["RSLT"]= df.inp2.map(diffstr)
df= df.drop(columns=["inp2","lastch","idchng"])
print(df,"\n")
```

Outputs:

```
# test data:
    ID            input  OUTPUT
0   1              A,B       1
1   1            B,C,D       2
2   1                C       1
3   2              E,f       1
4   2            A,B,C       3
5   3                E       0
6   4  A,A,B,A,C,D,A,E       6 

   ID            input  OUTPUT  idchng lastch
0   1              A,B       1   False    NaN
1   1            B,C,D       2   False      B
2   1                C       1   False      D
3   2              E,f       1    True      C
4   2            A,B,C       3   False      f
5   3                E       0    True      C
6   4  A,A,B,A,C,D,A,E       6    True      E 

   ID            input  OUTPUT  RSLT
0   1              A,B       1     1
1   1            B,C,D       2     2
2   1                C       1     1
3   2              E,f       1     1
4   2            A,B,C       3     3
5   3                E       0     0
6   4  A,A,B,A,C,D,A,E       6     6
```